# Force NOW to return new timestamps without committing the transaction

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I'm aware that, in PostgreSQL, the return value of `NOW()` is the *transaction begin timestamp*. So if you use `NOW()` multiple times in the same transaction it will always return the same value.

And that's good in my book.

But I have a small issue with unit-tests in a client application with this and would love to be able to tell PostgreSQL to (temporarily) disable this if at all possible.

The reason I don't want to (can't) use another timestamp function like `clock_timestamp()` is because the function call to `NOW()` sits inside of a trigger, and in production code I *want* the "transaction-start" behaviour.

But in my unit-tests I'm patching the API-level "commit" function so I don't accidentally commit real data to the database during testing (don't worry, I don't use the production DB during testing). So during unit-tests the `commit` never hits the DB, so I don't get new transaction timestamps.

The database uses temporal tables, and new entries are only appended to the history tables if the timestamp changes to ensure we only consolidate *one* entry in the history table per transaction.

But when testing the temporal-table behaviour this now causes no entry to ever show up in the history tables. The key fragment of the temporal-table trigger is this:

```
new_validity_period = tstzrange(
    lower(OLD.validity_period),
    NOW(),
    '[)'
);
IF isempty(new_validity_period) THEN
    RAISE DEBUG 'New entry % will not introduce a new history item', OLD;
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;
```

So when I do an "insert" operation in my unit-test, and the transaction-time is '2020-01-01 01:02:03', then the validity-period for that entry will be `[2020-01-01 01:02:02,)`. If, still in the same unit-test, I delete the entry (and to test whether it appears in the history table), the operation happens in the same TX, and the code above will read like this:

```
new_validity_perion = tstzrange(
    '2020-01-01 01:02:03', -- the lower-bound of the 'OLD' row
    '2020-01-01 01:02:03', -- the result of 'NOW()'
    '[)'
)
-- resulting in an empty range because the two timestamps are identical
IF isempty(new_validity_periond) THEN  -- <- Resulting to TRUE
    ...
    RETURN OLD;  -- returning here, not continuing to store the history entry
END IF;
-- code below here is skipped
```

Is there a way to configure PG to *always* return the wall-time when calling `NOW()`? The tests are run against a docker-container so I have full control over the server-config. But it would be even better if I could change the behaviour by setting the config via an SQL command, so I could *only* change the behaviour for the temporal-table tests.

If that is not possible I would need to use a different database-session/transaction setup for those tests. This is also fine, but I was wondering if I could control this PG behaviour.

### Appendix: Unit-Test transaction isolation

This is the code I use to isolate the commit calls in user-code:

```python
@fixture
def rb_session():
    """
    Returns a session which will always be rolled back.
    """

    engine = create_engine(Configurations.getenv("IPBASE_DATABASE_DSN"))

    # Get a *specific* connection from the pool
    connection = engine.connect()
    # Explicitly start a new connection on the connection we got
    # This makes the normal "session.begin()" and "session.commit()"
    # calls in SQLAlchemy no-ops as there is already a transaction
    # in progress.
    transaction = connection.begin()
    # Ensure we use the "primed" connection for all our SQLAlchemy
    # session needs in our unit-tests.
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        transaction.rollback()
        session.close()
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that that is questionable practice. Any way in which your tests differ from the productive environment increases the danger of testing the wrong thing.

Anyway, you could not use `now()`, but a different function, say `mytimestamp()`. On your test system, the function is defined as

```
CREATE FUNCTION mytimestamp() RETURNS timestamp with time zone
   LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE AS
'SELECT clock_timestamp()';
```

In the production database, you use

```
CREATE FUNCTION mytimestamp() RETURNS timestamp with time zone
   LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE AS
'SELECT current_timestamp';
```

Then you get what you want.  The only difference is that `current_timestamp` (or `now()`, which is the same thing) is `STABLE`, not `VOLATILE`, which may make queries behave differently (or not, if the function is inlined). But that's exactly the kind of thing that I warned you about in the beginning.

Comment: I agree that it is questionable practice. I have poured a lot of thought into it and isolated the "ugly parts" pretty well (only 3 out of ~800 tests). The DB is currently identical to the production system and don't feel comfortable about having 2 differing implementaions of `mytimestamp`. I would prefer to change the behaviour of NOW in isolation if possible. I have switched to a different test-fixture which uses "true commits" for the tests in question (leaving other tests unmodified) and it works.  But making "NOW" behave differently would clean this up a bit.

Comment: What is the difference? You can hack up PostgreSQL, but in effect that would not be much different.

Comment: I prefer to keep these kind of obscure hacks in the application code rather than the database. Having a team with mostly developers it makes it easier to debug should anything happen. The team has much more experience in application code than PL/SQL and otehr DB internals. So in the end it's just a decision I took to avoid making team-mates life unnecessarily difficult. If it were the other way around, I'd have put it in the DB.

Comment: Well, I don't know a different solution, short of modifying PostgreSQL core.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave this open for a few more days just in case something comes up. If not I'll accept your answer as it is valid.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe While it doesn't seem possible to overwrite `pg_catalog.now` itself, I see nothing that would prevent you from putting your `mytimestamp` in a `override` schema with the name `now`, and giving that schema priority over `pg_catalog` in the `search_path`. No hacking on core required :-)

Comment: @Bergi True. To me, that seems just as hacky, or even more so. But perhaps OP likes it better.